# HTML table rows with Vue(2) binding

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I have a shopping cart / order list that I bound to an array which worked fine.

I recently added a row number for each item added to the array, and also a button row.
The problem is I bound them to a current row like so

```html
<div id="table">
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Product</th>
          <th scope="col">Type</th>
          <th scope="col">Attribute</th>
          <th scope="col">Height</th>
          <th scope="col">Width</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
          <th width="1%" scope="col">Remove</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(item, index) in table_products">
            <td>{{ index +1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.product }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.type }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.attribute }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.height }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.width }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteRow(index)">X</button></td>
          </tr> 
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I never had a problem because the bound item values were null so the row was never created. But now Index and the button create the first row of the table.

Is there a way I can clear the array on page load, or am I going at this the wrong way?

[image: The table on page load]

edit : added my vue component for context

```
var table_products = new Vue ({
   el : '#table',
   data : {
     table_products : [{
    }]
   },
```

Comment: If you don't want any rows, don't put anything in the `table_products` array. At the moment, it seems you have one array element with empty properties for `product`, `type`, etc

Comment: @Phil Those elements are null, it's only the index and remove button that creates the row

Comment: if, for some odd reason, you can't have an ampty array for `table_products` when there's no data, how about `<tbody v-if="table_products[0].product">`

Comment: Initialise `table_products` as `[]`, **not** `[{}]`

Comment: @Phil Thanks, that sorted it. Although I don't understand why. That being said I've only been learning this for a month now

Comment: why? because the way you've initialised it you have an item in that array - which is why it's displayed, because you display it

Comment: Put simple, `[]` is an empty array. `[{}]` is an array with one element (an empty object). The number of rows rendered in your table is produced from the number of elements in your array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initialized  `table_products [{}]` instead of `[]`

It had an empty object in the array from initialization so it had an element.
Initializing an empty array instead fixed this issue as it did not have an element.

Thanks to Phil in the comments